# Is apache-beam a good choice when the event time ordering has to preserved when writing to sink?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm considering using apache beam to write a streaming pipeline to apply a stream of mutations to replicate events from a source database into a destination database in the order of event time. The source could be either kafka or pubsub.

An example would be something like [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dynamodb-spanner-migration/blob/master/dataflow/src/main/java/com/example/spanner_migration/SpannerStreamingWrite.java) except that the order in which the mutations are applied to the sink must be in order in which they arrived.

I did go over some of the previous questions asked on preserving order:

- [Processing Total Ordering of Events By Key using Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888719/processing-total-ordering-of-events-by-key-using-apache-beam)
- [Sort elements within a fixed window - Cloud Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968634/sort-elements-within-a-fixed-window-cloud-dataflow) - This seems to be same use case i'm interested in.

I understand that if I go down the apache beam road i would have to

1. choose a windowing strategy with accommodation for late data (either a fixed windowing strategy with a allowed lateness or  with global window, have triggers to emit panes and buffer for late data)
2. apply transformations
3. GroupByKey over a single key(so that everthing goes to the same worker), sort and write to sink

In addition to the above, I would have to make sure the windows(if i follow a fixed window strategy) are executed in order. Step 3 is bound to be the bottleneck.

If [2] above in the list of steps is a lot of computation then apache beam would make sense to take advantage of parallelism which beam offers. But if [2] is just a simple one to one mapping, does apache beam make sense for this replication usecase. Please let me know if i'm missing something.

Note: We do have a batch pipeline on dataflow using apache beam to load a datadump on gcs to database where the entire data is on disk and the order in which its written to sink does not matter.

Comment: Since you want to guarantee the order of events, Kafka would be a better approach, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering), Pub/Sub de-emphasizes the need for order as it's not aimed for that. Take a look at [this Kafka article](https://medium.com/@felipedutratine/kafka-ordering-guarantees-99320db8f87f). If you want to have a global ordering, you will need to have only 1 partition for topic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is not about using pub/sub vs kafka. My question is about the processing subsystem. Even if i use kafka(with a single partition) and if i use apache beam it cannot guarantee order. As i mentioned above the only way to guarantee order is groupby on a single key. I wanted to know if this is a effective use of apache beam.

Comment: The other option while using apache beam is to have parallel writes and make sure the database is usable only till the output watermark time of the last beam stage(requires database support)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWxSLmkWPm4&t=1249s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserving order it's possible, but not sure if it's straightforward or efficient.

It also depends on how much data (elements/sec) you're expecting as well as what the sink type is. Potentially you could have the pipeline write out ordered entries to GCS, and the sink just reads the files in, in order, as a secondary process.

Your other option, of using  parallel writes and make sure the database is usable only till the output watermark time of the last beam stage, it's  maybe doable, but not really the core use case of Dataflow/Apache Beam.

Maybe there could be ways to process the stream out of order, but write to an intermediate sink that can easily be read from in order. i.e. writing out the mutation batches with a step or file number that can easily be used to order the files when applied to the final sink.

The window + write to final sink architecture is going to be difficult to get right, probably too complex for low volume of elements, and too inefficient for large volume. [This](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) is a good example of what this could look like.

But again, keep in mind that all this approaches are definitely not the core use case for Dataflow/Apache Beam.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for the answer.  

1) The secondary process that you envision that will write the ordered entries from GCS to the sink - I assume that is outside the scope of beam?  

2) Regarding the second option  to make sure the database is usable only till output watermark time - Is the output watermark time of a pipeline stage available for external systems?  

3) By "window + write to final sink architecture" do you mean the "window+sort+write" model in the question to ensure order or the intermediate sink model in your answer?